# iPad 2 vs iPad 3 stylus sensitivity

Tags: ipad

My iPad 3 is noticibly less sensitive to my stylus than my iPad 2. (For instance, on my iPad 2, barely brushing my stylus against the screen, even in the slightest, has an effect; on my iPad 3, I must apply enough pressure to visibly deform the tip of the stylus.)

My question is: is there a setting to change this sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to adjust the pressure sensitivity unfortunately. However, there are several pressure sensitive styluses (styli? I've never had to pluralise stylus before) on  the market or at least in development.

Check out the [Jot-Touch](http://adonit.net/product/jot-touch/).

The [Pressure Pen](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/option8/pressurepen-the-open-source-pressure-sensitive-sty) and Ten One's [Blue Tiger](http://www.tenonedesign.com/bluetiger) are still in development.

Wacom's [Bamboo Pen](https://www.wacom.com/en/Store/Bamboo-for-iPad.aspx) isn't pressure sensitive, but it does improve pressure sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own using extremely fine steel wool (does not harm the glass in any way).  There are Youtube videos on how to make them.  The resulting stylus is infinitely more sensitive than the dozen or so commercial styli I have tried on both an iPad 2 and 3.  It's more like a paint brush than a stylus in fact, though there are ways to stiffen it just slightly and get a perfect "happy medium".  Check Youtube and you should be able to find more specifics.